# hiding element on blur, when it is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why my function is not working.
It is showing up the login form, but when I blur (click somewhere else than the form) it is not hiding.

here is my buggy code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#login-btn', function(){ 
      var $form = $("#login");
      $form.show("slow" );
      $("#login").on('blur', function (){
        $form.hide("slow");
       });      
 });
```

Comment: Can you share the `html` part? :)

Comment: Your blur event isn't being added until you click `#login-btn`. What palaѕн suggested gets around that.

Comment: You can't focus or blur a `form`.

Comment: Ah, Shikiryu has a good point. You might need to replace `blur` with `focusout` (in palash's answer) so the event bubbles up to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not want this blur to be handled only when click event gets fired.
Move the blur event out of the click event

```
var $form = $("#login");    
$(document).on('click', '#login-btn', function(){ 
    $form.show("slow" );  
    $('#loginUsername').focus(); 
});
$form.on('focusout', function (){
    $form.hide("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var $form = $("#login");
$(document).on('click', '#login-btn', function () {    
    $form.show("slow");
}).on('blur', '#login', function () {
    $form.hide("slow");
});
```